# TypeError: tempTable is null

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script that prompts you to enter a low temperature and a high one. When you click add temperatures, it displays todays date, low temp, and high temp, and the average of low temps and high temps. Each time you enter these temps, the previous date before the last is displayed with those temps and the averages. When I try to run the code I get this: `TypeError: tempTable is null`. Any suggestions?

```js
    (function() {
      //Array to hold temp data
      var temperatures = new Array();

      // function which updates the array
      function addTemp() {
        var lowTemp = document.getElementById("lowTemp").value;
        var highTemp = document.getElementById("highTemp").value;
        if (lowTemp.length === 0 || highTemp.length === 0) {
          alert("Valid low and high temperatures must be entered!");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("output").style.display = "block";
          // Add new temperatures to the array
          // Current date
          var d = new Date();
          if (temperatures.length == 0) {
            // Current date if it is 1st temperature
            temperatures.push(new Array(d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getFullYear(), lowTemp, highTemp));
          } else {
            // 1 day before last date
            newDate = temperatures[temperatures.length - 1][1] - 1;
            temperatures.push(new Array(d.getMonth(), newDate, d.getFullYear(), lowTemp, highTemp));
          }
          // Create the output table
          var tempTable = document.getElementById("tempTable");
          tempTable.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Low Temperatures</th><th>High Temperatures</th></tr>";
          // Loop over the array and create the table
          // Also calculate the averages
          var avgLow = 0;
          var avgHigh = 0;
          temperatures.forEach(function(entry) {
            var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            newRow.innerHTML = '<td>' + entry[0] + '/' + entry[1] + '/' + entry[2] + '</td><td align="right">' + entry[3] + '</td><td align="right">' + entry[4] + '</td>';
            tempTable.appendChild(newRow);
            avgLow += parseInt(entry[3]);
            avgHigh += parseInt(entry[4]);
          });
          // Add the row for average
          avgLow /= temperatures.length;
          avgHigh /= temperatures.length;
          avgLow = avgLow.toFixed(1)
          avgHigh = avgHigh.toFixed(1)
          var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
          newRow.innerHTML = '<td>Averages</td><td align="right">' + avgLow + '</td><td align="right">' + avgHigh + '</td>';
          tempTable.appendChild(newRow);
          //Add row for lowest temp
          var minTemp = Math.min.apply(lowTemp.value);
          var key = lowTemp.indexOf(d);
          var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
          newRow.innerHTML = '<td colspan="3"> The lowest temp of' + minTemp + 'occured on' + key + '</td>';
          tempTable.appendChild(newRow);
        }
        return false;
      }

      function init() {
          'use strict';
          document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addTemp;
        } // End of init() function.
      window.onload = init;
    })();
```

Comment: The only way (based on your code) to get that error is if you don't have an element with id `tempTable` in you markup.

Comment: Please put html also it looks like you may noy have `tempTable` as id

Comment: There is no element with the id  attribute with the value tempTable. Make sure your code is after the html

Answer (score 0):

The error means that when your code executed at that time `temptable` was not set possibly because your JS code is rendering prior to DOM element loaded.

`var tempTable = document.getElementById("tempTable");`

Also execute `init()` in `DomContentLoaded` instead of `window.onload`.

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    init();
  });`

Comment: *"Also execute init() in DomContentLoaded instead of window.onload."* - Why? Good practice in a general sense, but how would that help with the OP's current problem?